# I am trying to create a search bar using javascript in VISUAL STUDIO but I have not yet succeeded

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

html File:
I have used some divs and inside i have introduced some titles and images.

In the search bar i just want that when i enter a title the full div appears on the screen when i search.

```
<body>
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="searchbar" onkeyup="search_bar()">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="s10plus" id="divs">
        <h2>Samsung Galaxy S10 Plus</h2>
        <img src="Images/s10plus.png"></img>
        <p id="precios10">Price : $600</p>
    </div>
    <div class="samsunga10">
        <h2>Samsung Galaxy A10</h2>
        <img src="Images/a10.png"></img>
        <p id="precioa">Price:$600</p>
    </div>
    <div class="samsunga20">
        <h2>Samsung Galaxy A20</h2>
        <img src="Images/a20.png"></img>
        <p id="precio">Price:$600</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

file.js

```
function search_bar() {
    var a;
    var search = document.getElementById('searchbar');
    var filter = search.input.toLowerCase();
    var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('s10plus');
    var nodes = ul.getElementsByTagName('h2').length;

    for (i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
        a = nodes[i].getElementsByTagName('h2')[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            nodes[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            nodes[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean you "have not yet succeeded?" Are you seeing an error? What's the actual issue you have?

Answer (score 0):

Could you share a Codepen or Codesandbox or add a snipped here in SO?

in your Js code:
"li" is not defined which makes it hard to understand your code exactly.
Also, setting display: "", is not a valid css property. I recommend setting it to display: "inherit".

The class "s10plus" at:

```
          var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('s10plus');
```

will always get 1 element since in your html only one div has that class.

Try to adjust these issues and see if you can get any further

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. But 
first I want to know if the search bar shows me the div that I have entered, if it shows me then I will be able to work for other divs.